# Cordova Build issue since version 12.0.0

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios

I have recently updated to cordova 12.0.0, lib 12.0.1 - every since when I try to perform add/create/remove commands I get the message.

cordova platform ios -d
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "code" argument must be of type number. Received type string ('ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR')
at process.set [as exitCode] (node:internal/bootstrap/node:123:9)
at /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:32:22

Xcode: 15
Node: 21.7.1

Im trying to install platform cordova-ios:7.0.1 but I have also tried going as far back as @6.3.0 with no luck.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

I tracked the problem down to an incorrectly typed XML row. Correcting this row allowed the ios to install and compile.